# Object & Shape Recognition from webcam

Tags: actionscript-3, webcam, image-recognition, object-recognition

I need to create an application to get input from a webcam or camera connected to a computer and detect certain 3d objects.

I could do this from a .3ds file or something else? I'm not quite sure.

I am pretty sure it is possible with flash as3? I have been looking into openCV but i can't find any examples of this kind of thing.

Any help would be great, and if you have any further questions to understand more. please ask.

Thanks

Frank

EDIT: Ow and i need this to be a web based solution. so i was thinking of python, AS3 something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

To detect a "3D object" through an inherently 2D medium (a bitmap captured by a camera) is a very complex thing, and requires the detection of lit and shaded areas and how they move in respect to an often known light source. What you likely want to do instead (unless you have access to hardware with a depth buffer, e.g. the Kinect) is to analyze the 2D picture for 2D shapes, i.e. the silhouette of the object that you're looking for.

Have a look at [ASFEAT](http://blog.inspirit.ru/?tag=asfeat) and [IN2AR](http://www.in2ar.com/), which are made by the same russian wunderkind as ASSURF, but actively developed an not using patented algorithms.

OpenCV (the port of which to Flash/AS3 is called [Marilena](http://www.francois-tarlier.com/blog/marilena-opencv-port-to-actionscript-3-as3-flash/)) might do the trick, but it's not as optimized for Flash, and requires fairly complex descriptor files. I believe the only ones that are readily available are for face detection.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will check those out. I'v been googling all day and haven't come across those in my querys, There is too much facial detection software out there it gets annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably [ASSURF](http://code.google.com/p/in-spirit/wiki/ASSURF), it won't do detection of 3D models but it will do 2D shapes.